# Multiple queries end with unpredictably sorted result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

There are few hundred documents in my database. Schema is very simple:

```
var firmsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  sections: [String],
});
```

I want to query documents and iterate over:

```
{{#each sections}}
  {{sectionName}}
  {{#each firms}}
    {{firmName}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Simple:

```
const SECTIONS = ['name_one', 'name_two', 'name_three'];
const UNSORTED_SECTION_NAME = 'unsorted';

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var showFirms = function showSection (i, acc) {
    if (i < 0) return;
    let query = SECTIONS[i] ? {sections: SECTIONS[i]} : {sections: {$nin: SECTIONS}};
    let key = SECTIONS[i] || UNSORTED_SECTION_NAME;
    Firms.find(query).
    then((result) => {
      acc.push({
        section: key,
        firms: result,
      });
      if (i === SECTIONS.length) {
        acc = acc.sort((a, b) => (a.section > b.section));
        res.render('template', {
          sections: acc,
        });
      }
    }).
    then(showSection (i - 1, acc));
  }
  showFirms(SECTIONS.length, []);
};
```

Works fine. Except it returns `acc` randomly and unpredictably sorted. I mean `'name_two'` section can follow `'name_one'` or vise versa.

I thought `.sort()` at the end of promises chain would be a silver bullet here and solve all asynchronous problems, but it didn't.

Of course i can sort `acc` with handlebars helper after i pass it to my template, but it is so ridiculously strange i can't sort it right after all queries have been done in my `showFirms` function.

Can you give me some advise please?

Comment: Shouldn't sort be part of your request to mongodb? If it's unpredictable in it return values, I don't see how you could handle sorting outside of the query

Comment: You are making comparaison between strings. Ex: `name_one` > `name_two`. This is wrong

Comment: The problem here is that i run multiple requests (`showSection` is a recursive function), then i collect all results in accumulator `acc` and then pass to my template. If sort is a part of each request it simply would sort elements inside each response. This is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why can't i do it, @GrégoryNEUT? In JavaScript 'a' is always less then 'b' and vise versa. At least it will always return some predictable result. My code passes `acc` to my template in random and unpredictable order.

Comment: It's bad because you surely won't let `name_one`, `name_two`... and it's awful in order of evolutivity and maintainance. Who goes first : `name_two` or `name_one`, I had to remember of `a-z` order myself to figure it out.

Comment: Tho I think you mean `if (i === 0)` and not `if (i === SECTIONS.length)`

Comment: Please tell a little more on how you want to sort?

Comment: @Grégory NEUT, good suggestion! I've started with `if (i === 0)` and figured out that `showSection` returns values of `acc` in some kind of "backward order". It's a little bit magical and still i don't have solid understanding of that's going on here, but i know for sure that when i pass `acc` to my template it contains all responses to my queries.

Comment: @Tolsee, each element of `acc` is an object. `key` has a section name or `unsorted` if no one present, `firms` is a collection of documents with corresponding value of `sections` field. I want to sort this array by key `key` alphabetically for example (doesn't really matter how, i just want to have an opportunity to sort it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this remake of your code. Instead of getting the data one by one, we gotta get them on the same time (asynchronously) and then treat the return.

If you have any questions I am here, this code is untested so give me a feedback. This is an example of how you can change your code.

```
const showFirms = function showSection() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get the keys for the queries
    const keys = SECTIONS.map(x => x || UNSORTED_SECTION_NAME);

    // For each sections we gonna call a find request
    const promises = SECTIONS.map((x, xi) => {
      const query = x ? {
        sections: x,
      } : {
        sections: {
          $nin: SECTIONS,
        },
      };

      const key = keys[xi];

      return Firms.find(query);
    });

    // Resolve all promises
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((rets) => {
        // Use the finds results to build an acc array
        const accs = rets.map((x, xi) => ({
          section: keys[xi],
          firms: x,
        }));

        // Change the sort -> ;) #comments
        const sortedAccs = accs.sort((a, b) => (a.section > b.section));

        resolve(sortedAccs);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```

---

How to use it

```
showFirms()
  .then(accs => res.render('template', {
    sections: accs,
  }))
  .catch(err => console.log(`I have an error ${err.toString()}`));
```

Comment: Awesome job! Little bit difficult for me to understand as i'm new with promises thing in EcmaScript, but it returns everything i need in a predictable way. Will try to work as an interpretor few more times to get solid understanding of what's going on here. Also, as i see this solution makes queries for predefined keys in `SECTIONS` array and doesn't return documents without or with some other values in sections field. Will try to make some improvements.

Comment: And it's still confusing that i don't understand whats wrong with my initial code. I don't belive in magic.

Comment: The problem in your initial code was that you were sending an pointer to the `acc` array to the page you wanna render after the first find call. Then asynchronously and so *randomly*, the other find get performed and fill up the `acc` object. When you was using `acc` it was pure *random* about how many requests did finished and get pushed to `acc`.

Comment: Thanks. I believe i see the initial problem now.

Comment: I rewrote your code a little bit. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Grégory NEUTS excellent solution. I simplified some things and made the "other sections case" work. I even dropped out sort functionality. Eventual result returns in order of sections as they were declared in the initial `SECTIONS` array, so now i can just reorder it to control output.

```
const showFirms = function () {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

    const extendedSections = SECTIONS.slice();
    extendedSections.push(UNSORTED_SECTION_NAME);

    const promises = extendedSections.map((section) => {
      const unsortedCase = section === UNSORTED_SECTION_NAME;
      const query = unsortedCase ? {sections: {$nin: SECTIONS}} : {sections: section};
      return Firms.find(query);
    })

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((allResponces) => {
        const sectionsData = allResponces.map((response, i) => ({
          section: extendedSections[i],
          firms: response,
        }));
        resolve(sectionsData);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```